# Responding when a USB device is connected

Tags: macos

Is there a way to launch an app automatically when a user connects a USB device?

I have read about launch daemons and launch agents, and also Launch Services, but the documentation doesn't answer my question: how can I react when the user plugs in a device?

I've noticed in the Console that, if i unplug the device nothing happens, but if I plug it again then something in system does react.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to try to clarify what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html

have you tried the "StarOnMount" key mentioned in the launchd plist documentation?

your binary can be registered as an OnDemand LaunchAgent and/or LaunchDameon and will be launched if a new filesystem mounted.